# How to load Toolbar layout in Xamarin Android Fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, toolbar

I'm trying to create a basic toolbar that I can place clickable icons on. This will be inside a separate fragment to the starting activity page.

Fragment Code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        //Inflates the new xml into the fragment 
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.chord_progression, container, false);
        mToolbar = view.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)this.Activity).SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)this.Activity).SupportActionBar.Title = "Progression Maker";

        //Button that when pressed returns to the login screen
        btnLogout = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogout);
        btnLogout.Click += (sender, EventArts) =>
        {
            //Drops back into main activity
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

        //Calls the to play the chords selected by the user
        btnPlay = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.PlayChords);
        btnPlay.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => PlayChords(sender, EventArgs);

        //Calls this to generate random chords from the selected key
        btnRandomise = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRandomise);
        btnRandomise.Click += (sender, EventArgs) => randomiseChords(sender, EventArgs);

        //Spinners to store tonality and key signatures
        key_Spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.key_Spinner);
        tonality_Spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.tonality_Spinner);

        //Spinners that allow the user to select the individual chord they want to use
        chord1_spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.chord1);
        chord2_spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.chord2);
        chord3_spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.chord3);
        chord4_spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.chord4);

        chord1_spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(generateChordOne);
        chord2_spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(generateChordTwo);
        chord3_spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(generateChordThree);
        chord4_spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(generateChordFour);

        //Calls procedure that changes the spinners content based on the selection of another
        tonality_Spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(tonalitySpinner_ItemSelected);
        key_Spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(keySpinner_ItemSelected);

        //Brings up the save dialog
        btnSave = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.SaveButton);
        btnSave.Click += (sender, EventArgs) =>
        {
            //Ensures thet the user is unable to access save function if they have nothing to save
            if (tonality_Spinner.SelectedItemPosition == 0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Nothing to save!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else if (UserID == "-1" && tonality_Spinner.SelectedItemPosition != 0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "You cannot save progressions as a guest!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else if (UserID == "-1" && tonality_Spinner.SelectedItemPosition == 0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "You cannot save progressions as a guest! And there's nothing to save!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else 
            {
                //Gets the contents of the selected items of the spinners as strings
                string chord1 = chord1_spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string chord2 = chord2_spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string chord3 = chord3_spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string chord4 = chord4_spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string tonality = tonality_Spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string keysig = key_Spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();

                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                DialogSave Save_Dialog = new DialogSave(chord1, chord2, chord3, chord4, tonality, keysig, UserID);
                Save_Dialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
            }

        };

        btnLoad = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.LoadButton);
        btnLoad.Click += (sender, EventArgs) =>
        {
            if (UserID == "-1")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Can't load as a guest!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                btnLoad_Click(sender, EventArgs);
            }
        };


        //Brings up the dialog fragment for the help tab
        btnHelp = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.HelpButton);
        btnHelp.Click += (sender, EventArgs) =>
        {
            //Pull up dialog
            FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            DialogHelp Help_Dialog = new DialogHelp();
            Help_Dialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
        };

        if (UserID == "-1")
        {
            btnLogout.Text = "Sign In";
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        string textToShow;
        if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_info)
            textToShow = "Learn more about us affa";
        else
            textToShow = "overflooow";
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Layout for fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id = "@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight = "?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background = "?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation = "4dp"
        android:theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_info"
        android:icon ="@drawable/ic_help_icon"
        app:showAsAction ="ifRoom"
        android:title ="Info"/>
  <item android:id ="@+id/menu_overflow"
        app:showAsAction ="never"
        android:title="Overflow"/>
</menu>
```

Style page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

I have already made my main activity take from 'AppCompatActivity'.
I also already have reference my theme in the Activity.
I have also included 'SetHasOptionsMenu(true)' in the OnCreate.
The problem is it sets the title just fine but it doesn't seem to be calling the OnCreateOptionsMenu.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to add custom toolbar to replace default toolbar, I suggest you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/tool-bar/replacing-the-action-bar, According to your code, I am not sure what you want to do, and where is chord_progression layout?

Comment: Thats the chord progression fragment I included, I want to add the toolbar to this fragment.

Comment: I solved it, I had to add onCreateOptionsMenu into my main activity so that my fragment could call on it.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your issue by yourself, if you are free, please post reply to share your solution here, and mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include this your main activity to allow your fragment to create the toolbar:

```
 public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: I will do, just says I have to wait 3 hours as of now.